# URL-Repeater-Field with Angular 5 and FormArray of FormControls

Tags: angular, forms, repeater, angular5, formarray

I need a list of urls in a form. A repeaterfield. Something like this:
[image: repeater field]

Im using a FormGroup which I initialise like this:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    otherField: ['', Validators.required],
    urls: this.fb.array([
        new FormControl('test'),
        new FormControl('test2')
    ]),
.
.
.
});
```

Some getter methods:

```
  private get urls() { return this.myForm .get('urls'); }
  private get otherField() { return this.myForm .get('otherField'); }
```

On the HTML-Side it looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="otherField">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col mb-3" formArrayName="urls">
      <div class="input-group" *ngFor="let item of urls.controls; let i = index" >
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="???">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
           </button>
         </div>
       </div>       
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

This already displays the right amount of inputs (two in this minimal example). But how do I bind the date to the input? What can I use as formControllName?

Comment: What is `urls2`? There is no such form array in your TS file?

Comment: it has that name in my code, I made an error transfering my code to a minimal example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming `urls2` is a typo)

Since we are dealing with single formcontrols, we can use the index value of the iteration to refer to the form controls, so just add `[formControlName]="i"` for your inputs:

```
<div class="col mb-3" formArrayName="urls">
  <div class="input-group" *ngFor="let item of urls.controls; let i = index" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
   </div>       
 </div>
```

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x7gmg1?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: so obvious, thank you, I tryed adding this to the div, but not to the input